# next.js simple routing getting a 404 error

Tags: next.js

I'm getting started with next.js and following a tutorial.  I'm using next 13.4.19.  My tutorial tells me that if I create a contact.tsx under my app directory, I go to localhost:3000/contact.

[image: my folder structure]

My simple contact content:

```
import React from 'react';

const ContactPage = () => {
  return <div>Contact Page</div>;
};

export default ContactPage;
```

I tried both of the options below but got a 404 error for both.  Can someone help me figure out what I did wrong?
-http://localhost:3000/ContactPage
-http://localhost:3000/contact